# HTML Doesn't show after PHP INCLUDE

Tags: php, html, web

First of all, I read other discussions about my question on this website and I googled it. But none of them works for me!

I have a simple `HTML` code. And I want to call an external `PHP` in it with `INCLUDE` OR `REQUIRE`, but the problem is that the rest of the `HTML` does not show up after the `PHP`.

I have tested other `PHP` codes, like assigning a simple variable!!! And there wasn't any problem.

But when I try to use `INCLUDE`, the `HTML` codes after the `PHP`, does not work.

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>A</th>
        <th>B</th>
        <th>C</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php include("T.php"); ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
<Div> Hello </Div>
```

For example, the Hello word doesn't appear after `INCLUDE`.

Why? Can somebody help me?

Comment: What does `T.php` contain? Does the `</tbody>` appear in the source code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check if your t.php file exists.

```
$file = file_exists(t.php);

if($file) { 
echo "The file exists, maybe the problem comes from this file?";
} else {
echo "Pleas check the path of your file";
}
```

If the file exists, please check the file if it has a `die()` function or `exit()` which can lead the script to stop and that might be the reson why you can't see the html code, and if it's not it should show you an error, if it doesn't show you any error then please write this in your index.php.

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Let us know if it works please.

Comment: Thanks, Actually I had an exit function in my PHP file. As you said, I deleted that and my problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

HTML files will not be read for PHP. And the include statement needs to be read as PHP. If your file has any PHP inside it, it must be a .php file.

Comment: I changed it, but it does not work. @Cihan Kalmaz

Comment: my file is index.php !

Comment: "_If your file has any PHP inside it, it must be a .php file_" Not necessarily, a server can be set up to parse `.html` (or `.css`...) files as if they were `.php` files

Comment: <?php
    echo <<<EOT
    <div class="navbar navbar-static-top">
        <ul class="nav">
            <li class="home"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li class="about"><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li class="projects"><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
            <li class="resume"><a href="#">Resume</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
EOT;

?> Can you try like this?